# Populate a list with missing members of a sequence

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a collection of lists containing random elements of a sequence, say integers from 0 to 3.

```
sequence={0., 1., 2., 3.};
Table[RandomSample[sequence, RandomInteger[{1, 4}]], {5}]
```

> {{3., 0., 1.}, {3., 1., 0., 2.}, {1., 3.}, {1., 3., 0., 2.}, {0., 2., 
>     3.}}

How do I populate the lists so that the missing sequence members are filled?

> {{3., 0., 1., 2.}, {3., 1., 0., 2.}, {1., 3., 0., 2.}, {1., 3., 0.,
>   2.}, {0., 2., 3., 1.}}

Note: answers where elements are `Integer`s are fine but I'm also looking for answers which work for `Real` elements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work for any kind of list, not just numeric ones :)

```
sequence = {0., 1., 2., 3.};
list = Table[RandomSample[sequence, RandomInteger[{1, 4}]], {5}]
```

> {{2., 0.}, {0., 3.}, {2.}, {0., 3., 1.}, {1., 0., 2., 3.}}

```
#~Join~Complement[sequence, #] & /@ list
```

> {{2., 0., 1., 3.}, {0., 3., 1., 2.}, {2., 0., 1., 3.}, {0., 3., 1., 
>     2.}, {1., 0., 2., 3.}}

Comment: I could have sworn I looked for that `Complement` function in the docs... Nice one-liner!

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{2, 0}, {0, 3}, {2}, {0, 3, 1}, {1, 0, 2, 3}};
```

Using an unsorted sequence

```
s = {3, 0, 2, 1};
```

With `DeleteElements` (new in 13.1)

```
Join[#, DeleteElements[s, #]] & /@ list
```

{{2, 0, 3, 1}, {0, 3, 2, 1}, {2, 3, 0, 1}, {0, 3, 1, 2}, {1, 0, 2, 3}}

Compare to `Complement`

```
Join[#, Complement[s, #]] & /@ list
```

{{2, 0, 1, 3}, {0, 3, 1, 2}, {2, 0, 1, 3}, {0, 3, 1, 2}, {1, 0, 2, 3}}

`DeleteElements` doesn't sort the appended elements. But, working
with long lists, it is much slower than `Complement`.

Answer (score 2):

```
 list = {{2, 0}, {0, 3}, {2}, {0, 3, 1}, {1, 0, 2, 3}};  
  s = {0, 1, 2, 3};
```

Using `DeleteCases` and `Catenate`:

```
Catenate[{#, DeleteCases[s, Alternatives @@ #]}] & /@ list

(*{{2, 0, 1, 3}, {0, 3, 1, 2}, {2, 0, 1, 3}, {0, 3, 1, 2}, {1, 0, 2, 3}}*)
```